# Javascript to Angular 2 : document.querySelector('el').emit('em') to @viewChild

Tags: angular, aframe, viewchild, angular2-render

How to convert

HTML

```
<a-entity id="fading-cube" geometry="primitive: box" material="opacity: 1">
  <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('#fading-cube').emit('fade');
```

This is my code in Angular 2 that is not working.

```
@ViewChild('fading-cube') fadingCubeInput: any;

fadecube(){    

this.renderer.setProperty(this.fadingCubeInput.nativeElement,'emit',"fade")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your element with `@ViewChild()`, you can assign a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) to it:

```
<a-entity #fadingCube ... >
```

Then you can use that template variable name in code:

```
@ViewChild('fadingCube') fadingCubeInput: ElementRef;
```

You should be able to call `emit('fade')` after casting the HTMLElement as `any`:

```
(this.fadingCubeInput.nativeElement as any).emit('fade');
```

Comment: I did make the change for the ID previously.  It's the ".emit" that is giving me trouble.  I cannot seem to emit from the nativeElement

Comment: You can try calling `emit` as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)  I got it working and my code now looks like this.

`this.fadingCubeInput.nativeElement.emit('fade') `